# How to access static function of another class

Tags: java, javafx

I am creating a simple JavaFX program to display an alert box/window by passing parameters from one stage to another. Below given are my code for `Main` class, `Controller` class, `AlertBox` class and all its `FXML` codes. I simply want to call the `display` function( which is defined in `AlertBox` ) in `Controller` class with two parameters- Title and message. I'm using Scene Builder to build the UI of the program but in the `AlertBox` class, I'm unable to use the label and button in the display function. I'm getting this error:
`Non-static method 'mess' cannot be referenced from static context`
Somebody please tell me how to solve it so I can communicate between the stages.

Main.java

```
package sample;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.scene.Parent;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class Main extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception{
        Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("sample.fxml"));
        primaryStage.setTitle("Hello World");
        primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(root));
        primaryStage.show();
    }


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

sample.fxml

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import javafx.scene.control.Button?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.CheckBox?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.Label?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.AnchorPane?>

<AnchorPane maxHeight="-Infinity" maxWidth="-Infinity" minHeight="-Infinity" minWidth="-Infinity" prefHeight="400.0" prefWidth="600.0" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/9" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" fx:controller="sample.Controller">
   <children>
      <Button fx:id="button" layoutX="274.0" layoutY="188.0" mnemonicParsing="false" text="Go to Scene 2" />
      <Label fx:id="label" layoutX="279.0" layoutY="236.0" style="-fx-background-color: #eee;" text="This is Scene 1!" />
      <CheckBox layoutX="156.0" layoutY="86.0" mnemonicParsing="false" text="CheckBox" />
      <Button fx:id="alert" layoutX="274.0" layoutY="295.0" mnemonicParsing="false" text="Open Alert" />
   </children>
</AnchorPane>
```

Controller.java

```
    package sample;

import sample.AlertBox;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.ResourceBundle;
import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.fxml.Initializable;
import javafx.scene.Parent;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.stage.*;
import javafx.scene.*;

public class Controller implements Initializable{

    @FXML
    Label label;
    @FXML Button alert;

    @Override
    public void initialize(URL url, ResourceBundle rb){

        alert.setOnAction(even ->
                {
                    AlertBox.display("Title", "This is the message");
                }

        );


    }

}
```

AlertBox.java

```
    package sample;


import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.fxml.Initializable;
import javafx.scene.Parent;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.scene.layout.AnchorPane;
import javafx.stage.Modality;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.ResourceBundle;

public class AlertBox implements Initializable{
    @FXML Button winClose;
    @FXML Label mess;
    @FXML AnchorPane lay;


    @FXML
    public static void display(String title, String message){
        Stage window = new Stage();
        window.initModality(Modality.APPLICATION_MODAL);
        window.setTitle(title);
        mess.setText(message);
        winClose.setOnAction(e -> window.close());

            window.setScene(new Scene(lay));
            window.showAndWait();
 }


    @Override
    public void initialize(URL location, ResourceBundle resources) {}
}
```

AlertBox.fxml

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import javafx.scene.control.Button?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.Label?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.AnchorPane?>


<AnchorPane fx:id="lay" minHeight="250.0" minWidth="250.0" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/9" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" fx:controller="sample.AlertBox">
   <children>
      <Button fx:id="winClose" layoutX="69.0" layoutY="179.0" mnemonicParsing="false" text="Close the Window" />
      <Label fx:id="mess" layoutX="109.0" layoutY="120.0" prefHeight="17.0" prefWidth="68.0" />
   </children>
</AnchorPane>
```

Comment: Why `implements Initializable` in the `Alert` class?

Comment: This doesn't make any sense. If `AlertBox` is the controller for an FXML file, you need to load the FXML file. No matter what is static (and *nothing* here should be static), how are `mess` and `winClose` going to be initialized if you don't load the FXML?

Comment: Okay, I see why after looking at your code. You have some strange stuff going on here. You have an `FXML` for the `Alert` Class, but in the method `display()`, you seem to be creating a new `Stage`.

Comment: @Sedrick Yes, What I want to do here is, On the `Controller` class I'm linking a button to the method in `Alertbox` class and when The button is clicked, It'll make a new stage with `AlertBox.fxml` loaded on it. Since, the function is parameterized, I'm passing `title` and `message` for the box.

Comment: @James_D That's why I'm using `implements Initializable` to use the `@FXML` components